# Pyvmomi configure ESXi 'NTP Client Enabled' check box

Tags: vmware, esxi, pyvmomi

Using the below code its possible to update the start up policy of ntpd service in an  ESXi server,

```
con = connect.SmartConnect(host=host, user=user, pwd=pwd)
content = con.RetrieveContent()
cv = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
        container=content.rootFolder, type=[vim.HostSystem], recursive=True)

for child in cv.view:
    child.configManager.serviceSystem.UpdatePolicy(id='ntpd', policy='on')
```

There is no clue in the service

```
(vim.host.Service) {
dynamicType = <unset>,
dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
key = 'ntpd',
label = 'NTP Daemon',
required = false,
uninstallable = false,
running = false,
ruleset = (str) [
  'ntpClient'
],
policy = 'off',
sourcePackage = (vim.host.Service.SourcePackage) {
  dynamicType = <unset>,
  dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
  sourcePackageName = 'esx-base',
  description = 'This VIB contains all of the base functionality of 
  vSphere ESXi.'
  }
}
```

But how to mark the *NTP Client Enabled* check box for ESXi using Pyvmomi?

[image]

VMware version - 6.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`host.configManager.firewallSystem.EnableRuleset(id='ntpClient')`